# Confirmation of the creation of a record via email in apex Oracle

Tags: oracle, oracle-apex

I have this situation: I have a filling form, there I enter the details of sealing the object, I want to add an interesting function to the form, I want to send an e-mail in order to support the sealing permissions.
For example, I want to seal the doors, in the form I enter the email and press the send button, I receive a normer, which I must enter in the next field in the form, if the number is correct, I see the "create" button, if not, then the "Create" button does not visible
Has anyone already encountered this?

Answer (score 1):

To show (or not) certain items or buttons you can use

- conditions
- dynamic actions (Show)

In your case, dynamic action might be a better choice.

The part which is related to "if the number is correct" is handled by **validation**.

Comment: Thank you, but could you help me understand how to send SMS with a generated number to mail

Comment: SMS? No, sorry, I don't know how to do that. If you want to send mails, then use UTL_MAIL or UTL_SMTP  package.

Comment: sorry, i meant email to email, just such a situation i dont understand how to send a random number to an email and then check it

Comment: You'll have to store that "random number" somewhere; ideally, into the same table as the "object sealing" information. Then, it is a simple case of comparison whether user entered exactly the same number (if so, then show the CREATE button; if not, display an error message). You'd do that using a validation.

Comment: one more question i'm using to create a project environment https://apex.oracle.com how can i create utl_mail packages there

Comment: You can not; SYS should grant it to you, but I don't think that Oracle (as a corporation) will allow sending mails from their servers.

Comment: Littlefoot, thanks for the help, thanks to you I have dealt with this problem, can i ask you to look at another problem of mine https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58202158/hide-the-create-button-if-p-photo-is-null-and-p-mandatory-photo-yes

Answer (score 1):

If you want to send an email, simplest way is to use `APEX_MAIL`. https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/application-express/19.1/aeapi/APEX_MAIL.html#GUID-14F51C6D-CB82-4B38-AB6E-61C46E75596F

For some other options, have a look here: https://jeffkemponoracle.com/2016/04/email-made-easier/

If you want to send an SMS, there is no built-in support for this. You would need to send requests via an SMS gateway. By way of example, an API for integrating with one gateway (ClickSend) which might help you is: https://jeffkemponoracle.com/2016/08/send-sms-mms-and-voice-messages-from-oracle-plsql/